# How can "define" not be defined when loading with RequireJS?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

I'm struggling to understand why a module loaded with RequireJS does not have access to the `define` function.

In my HTML:

```
<script data-main="/assets/js/app/main.js" src="/assets/libs/require.js/2.1.9/require.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

In `main.js`:

```
// Initialize Require.js
require.config({
   baseUrl: 'http://test.dev/cart/assets',
   paths: {
      jquery: 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min'
   }
});

// Main app logic
require( ['jquery', 
          'js/app/cart', 
          'js/app/wizard',
          'js/lib/colorbox', 
          'js/lib/jvfloat'], function ($, Cart, Wizard, ColorBox, jvfloat) {

    // Initialize Cart
    Cart.init();

    // Initialize Wizard
    Wizard.init();
}

);
```

In that, `colorbox.js` loads just fine and is wrapped like:

```
define(['jquery'], function ( jQuery ) {
     // ...Colorbox code here
});
```

When it tries to load jvfloat.js, it throws:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined

Even though it is wrapped with the **exact** same wrapper as colorbox.

I even **tried** adding a shim (not that it makes sense to) to see if I can force the load...but that didn't work either:

```
shim: {
   'jvfloat': {
      deps: ['require','jquery'],
      exports: 'jvfloat'
   }
}
```

I've also tried removing the `define` wrapper, and setting my shim like this which is how the [documentation suggests to do it](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim):

```
shim: {
    'jvfloat': {
        deps: ['jquery'],
        exports: 'jQuery.fn.jvfloat'
    }
}
```

---

**TL;DR;** What can cause a library being loaded by RequireJS to not have access to the the `define` function?

Comment: If jvfloat is wrapped the same way that colorbox is, why are you using `shim`?  `shim` is for modules that _aren't_ wrapped with `define`.

Comment: I said I even *tried* using a shim. I understand its purpose. **jvFloat** is a jQuery plugin and so, to make sure it has it's dependency, I'm trying to get it to work with RequireJS and also to make sure the plugin gets added to the same instance of jQuery that RequireJS passes around.

Comment: I guess I focused on the code block and missed the short description above.  My mistake... This does seem like very strange behavior, `define` is in the global scope and _should_ be visible everywhere it isn't shadowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figured out a workaround using the **shim** part of the RequireJS config. What I had tried before used `jvfloat` as the array key, when I was supposed to use the full thing. So this works:

```
require.config({
  baseUrl: 'http://test.dev/cart/assets',
  paths: {
     jquery: 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min'
  },
  shim: {
     'js/lib/jvfloat': {
        deps: ['jquery'],
        exports: 'jQuery.fn.jvfloat'
     }
  }
});
```

Still have no idea how to use `define` for something like this but, oh well, this counts as a solution and may help somebody else in the future.